# Dynamically expand list in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm creating map dynamically in a list comprehension and then I'm trying to append generated map in every iteration to a list.

Here is a code:

```
 result = []
 temp_map = %{}

 for n <- 1..number do
   temp_map = Map.put_new(temp_map, :title, Enum.at(titles, n))
   temp_map = Map.put_new(temp_map, :content, Enum.at(contents, n))

   result = result ++ [temp_map]
 end
```

But that code returns this:

```
[[%{contents: "cont-2", title: "tit-2"}], [%{contents: "cont-2", title: nil}]]
```

My idea is having these lists:

```
titles = ["title-1", "title-2"]
contents = ["content-1", "content-2"]
```

generate structure like this:

```
[%{title: "title-1", content: "content-1"}, %{title: "title-2", content: "content-2"}]
```

I just need something to append to list dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use temporary variables in a comprehension (or elsewhere) like that because Elixir's immutability will give you unexpected results if you are not used to that.

#### Example

```elixir
items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

i = 0

for item <- items do
  i = i + 1
  IO.puts i
end
```

will output

```elixir
1
1
1
```

#### Solution:

I would try something like this (using [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2)):

```elixir
titles = ["title-1", "title-2"]
contents = ["content-1", "content-2"]

result = 
  Enum.zip(titles, contents)
  |> Enum.map(fn {title, content} -> %{title: title, content: content} end)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking in an OOP-oriented way, a more functional and correct approach would be using `Enum.zip/2` together with `Enum.map/2`

```
titles = ["title-1", "title-2"]
contents = ["content-1", "content-2"]

result = Enum.zip(titles, contents) 
  |> Enum.map(fn {title, content} -> %{title: title, content: content} end)

# result: 
# [%{content: "content-1", title: "title-1"},
#  %{content: "content-2", title: "title-2"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I will put the answer using the comprehension approach here:

```rb
for {t, c} <- Enum.zip(titles, contents),
  do: %{title: t, content: c}
#⇒ [
#  %{content: "content-1", title: "title-1"},
#  %{content: "content-2", title: "title-2"}
# ]
```